# Passing in filename as a python function

Tags: python, function

I am working through a MOOC MIT class: The following code will not let me pass in my .txt file as an arg and returns this error(below).I have not been able to figure out why because when the I do the f = open(file, 'r') and just pass in file, it works fine :

```
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

code below:

```
def load_cows(file):

    cow_dict = dict()

    f = open(file, 'r')



    for line in f:
        line_data = line.split(',')
        cow_dict[line_data[0]] = int(line_data[1])
    return cow_dict

    pass
```

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the right python file? The error refers to a variable named 'filename', while in code you use 'file'.

Comment: Because filename it's the name of a variable that you never declare

Comment: So where did you use the variable `filename`?

Comment: On and old file, I got it to work, sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the name of the file in quotes,
eg.

> load_cows('filename.txt')